# How to learn - Microsoft Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, scrum

I would like to learn TFS. I have a windows 7 64bit computer. Is there an express free version or a trial I can use? My main goal is to learn something about TFS for a scrum project I would like to learn to create.

Comment: you can try vsts.

Comment: Isnt VSTS and TFS different?

Comment: VSTS is online version of TFS with slight changes. I hope your goal is to learn scrum project management so you can use VSTS. its almost identical with on premises  TFS (if you are not keen on learning backend stuffs)

Comment: Oh, ok. I understand now. Thank you for that clarification

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to learn TFS is to [create a Visual Studio Team Services account](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=307137&clcid=0x409), which is the free (for 5 users) cloud version of TFS. You can use the extension called 'Sample Data Widget' that can generate enough sample data to play with the agile planning tools.

If you want to learn configuration and setup, [grab the free trial version, stick it in a VM and practice as much as you want](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/).

Or [download the VM which contains a pre-configured instance of TFS with sample data](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/). That makes it easier to get started. There is also a whole list of [hands-on labs that you can run through for both TFS and VSTS](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Wow, hey, that's great. Thanks so much for the links!

Comment: I didnt yet try the VM method because the sample data widget worked partially. It might be enough to play with VSTS. I will have a look at the VM if i cant learn enough. Having not tried the VM with TFS and sample data I will accept this as an answer I can try for later.